# Preprocess node and template overrides

Tags: theming, 8, hooks

I am using the preprocess_node hook to extract data from entity references and add them as custom variables which are then spat out in a twig template.

The problem is that now, these custom variables seemingly have no applicable template override.

EG previously, I could output {{ content.address }} (which would contain street name, postcode, country etc) in the node template, and then override the output with a field--node--field-* template.

Now, I am outputting {{ custom_address.postcode }} for example, but there is no apparent template I can make, looking at the twig theme debugging messages.

Is there a way I can use custom twig variables, from the preprocess_node hook, and have template overrides?